# Как отменить ProgressBas?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

При загрузке фрагмента использую ProgressBar:

xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:minHeight="20dip"
    android:maxHeight="20dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
```

java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //****************************************************
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            mProgressBar.setMax(mNumberOfTeams);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            //****************************************************
    }
```

в AsincTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(TeamStanding teamStanding) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//*****************************************************
}
```

Все работает и `ProgressBar` скрывается при окончании загрузки, но если
 загрузить следующий фрагмент и вернуться по иерархии назад - загруженный 
индикатор мозолит глаза!
    Уже переопределял `onPause()` - скрывал индикатор в нем - не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы просто неправильно выбрали метод, т.к. могу предположить у вас расположение элементов полностью на `XML` => при возобновлении приложения оно заново будет показывать девственно чистый макет.

Попробуйте реализовать уход прогресс бара в никуда в методе `onResume()`, думаю что должно помочь.

Comment: Если скрывать progressBar в onResume, то при первой же загрузке все скроется, я просто не понимаю почему не удается скрыть его в onPause()?

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите инициализацию `ProgressBar` из `onCreateView` в `OnPreExecute`...

В документации на сайте об этом написано:

> `OnPreExecute()`, вызывается в потоке пользовательского интерфейса
>   перед выполнением `asynctask`. Этот шаг обычно используется для
>   настройки задачи, например, отображения `ProgressBar` в
>   пользовательском интерфейсе.